# fwrite / phpunit / file rights conflict

Tags: php, json, linux, file-io

I'm writing a PHP-Script with Webinterface running on a VM-machine. The Developing takes Place on my local machine, where i run my unit tests via PHPUnit (from command line). Of Course I'm root on both ubuntu-machines

The problem comes when I apply a function, `jsonWrite($string)` , which writes the data from a array to an `.json` file . This file lies on the VM(Server), and has (this is a test environment :)) 777-rights. The function works pretty fine - UNTIL I use PHP-Unit, in which my test function, `testRun()` calls the function `run()` which uses `jsonWrite` amongst other

After that, the file rights change to 664, and the script can't access the `.json` file anymore, which I do not understand, since it originally owned that file.

Q1: How do i prevent phpunit from changing the file permissions when it calls the function?

Q2: How can I configure `fwrite()` or `fopen()` to set specific permissions on write?

I thank you in Advance for useful hints / answers!

Here is the code of the relevant functions:

```
public function jsonWrite($string)
{
    ... converting string to array $game ...

    $fp = fopen('game.json', 'w');   // var_dump($fp); -> gives false after phpunit run
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($game)); 
    fclose($fp);

    return $game;
}

public function run()
{
    ... 
    $this->calculate($this);
    $string= $this->display($this);
    $this->jsonWrite($string);
    return  $this;
}   

public function testRun()
{
    $actual = new BowlCount();
    $actual = $actual->run();
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {$this->assertInstanceOf('Frame', $actual->Frames[$i]);}
    ...
}
```

Comment: 664(rw,rw,r) should be enough - which user/group are involved (before and after)

Comment: You should basically never have a file that is 777 - even in test environments. 664 is fine - just make sure the ownership is correct.

Comment: Before:
 
game.json -rwxrwxrwx 1 tr0tt3l tr0tt3l   401 Nov  9 00:00

After:

game.json -rw-rw-r-- 1 tr0tt3l tr0tt3l   401 Nov  9 00:00


The Problem with identificating the users is: i can't really say if the user is tr0tt3l@VBtest or tr0tt3l@tr0tt3lmachine... If I can clear this somehow, please tell me how! THX!